# Check box Field

Tags: formula-field, checkbox

I am trying to create a checkbox field as checked if another field has value and Uncheck it if another field does not have any value

For eg: if DDS field has number I need the check box to ticked. If the DDS Field does Not have number the checkbox field should be unticked

Edited: firstly Sorry For not briefing, I tried to create a formula checkbox field by reference of Text Encrypted field. I came to know you cant build formulas using Text Encrypted field..

So i would like to ask a Suggestion what else can be done to. Should i create a record triggeredd Flow to Update the Checkbox field or is there anyothere method

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, there's not enough information to identify the issue that you're having. This site isn't a place to get your work done for free, so the expectation is that you've made an honest attempt to do this and will show us that attempt. You should [edit] your question to add your attempt (and any error messages that you're seeing). If you're new to Salesforce (or a part/feature thereof) then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a better place for you to build some/additional platform knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using a formula field for this matter.
The type should be checkbox.

If you are unsure how to build the formula you can use the following trailhead module.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/es/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/formula_fields

Comment: Given that the question was tagged with "formula-field", I kinda assumed that OP already knew it should be a formula field. I've downvoted this because this doesn't strike me as an answer to the question. Rather, this would be more appropriate as a comment on the question. We just don't have enough information yet to know where OP is stuck (and "do my work for me" type questions should not be answered in general).